Find values that are 6 characters long in a string, pipe delimited
We have thousands of rows of product data we've received from a vendor; one column includes a barcode column. Within the column are multiple barcode vales, PIPE (|) delimited. The "barcodes" are sometimes ASIN, UPC, or a random "custom" barcode value (alphanumeric). I am trying to find a way to grab the 6 digit code that the vendor uses for the item. The barcode column is also not in order, sometime the 6 digit code is in the first delimited block, middle, or last block. How can I used substrings or split_strings to get the 6 digit code for each line? I keep running into errors for multiple substring or invalied parameter pass to left/substring function.
013206000509|810709
095198500151|213217|658514398083
621361|778522366830|750574368973

e.g.
(Select value from string_split(barcode,'|') where len(value) = '6')

SUBSTRING(barcode, LEN(LEFT(barcode, CHARINDEX ('|', barcode))) + 1, LEN(barcode) - LEN(LEFT(barcode, CHARINDEX ('|', barcode))) - LEN(RIGHT(barcode, LEN(barcode) - CHARINDEX ('|', barcode))) - 1)



While asking a question, you need to provide a minimal reproducible example:
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements.
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL.
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Why wouldn't Select value from string_split(barcode,'|') x where len(value) = 6 work? Are you calling it a correlated subquery? Please post the whole query, this ain't the Highlights magazine

" I keep running into errors for multiple substring" - do you mean that sometimes there is more than one 6 character substring? If so how should those cases be treated?

Your initial attempt should work as a sub query.
SELECT *,
(Select Top (1) value from string_split(dataline,'|') x where len(value) = 6) as barcode
FROM ProductData

fiddle

select top (1) value might be wise...

This took care of it, not sure why I didn't think to do top (1) after receiving the multiple substring error. Maybe not enough coffee yet.
